# Oracle - Getting Mutating Table Exception in trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, unique-constraint

I would like to write a trigger that checks before insert on a table to see if there are existing entries in that table with the same `fk_id` and `active flag`. For example imagine the following table:

```
| row_id | fk_id |  active_flag |
| ------------------------------|
|    1   |   500 |         1    |
|    2   |   500 |         0    |
|    3   |   501 |         1    |
```

Say I want to insert a new row with `fk_id = 500` and `active_flag = 1`. I want to throw an exception on this because, based on my rules, you cannot have two rows with the same `fk_id` that are also *active* in this table at any given time.

I wrote a trigger to try and handle this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYSCHEMA.CHECK_DUPS_BIU

BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE_T FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    l_cnt NUMBER;
    e_dup EXCEPTION;
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO l_cnt
    FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE_T 
    WHERE fk_id = :new.fk_id
    AND active_flag > 0;

    IF(l_cnt > 0)
    THEN
        RAISE e_dup;
    END IF;

EXCEPTION 
 WHEN e_dup THEN
  raise_application_error(-20300, 'You cannot insert two active items with the same fk_id');
END CHECK_DUPS_BIU;
/
```

With this trigger it works completely fine on inserts but when I do an update, I am getting a Mutating table exception:

```
ORA-04091: table MYSCHEMA.CHECK_DUPS_BIU is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "MYSCHEMA.CHECK_DUPS_BIU ", line 12
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MYSCHEMA.CHECK_DUPS_BIU '
```

I did a little research on the issue and I read that a better way to deal with a situation like this *might be to use a constraint instead but I am not sure how to code such a constraint that checks on another column (the active_flag).

How can I implement such a check?

Comment: Are you sure that you are seeing the compiled code? A Mutating error occurs when you do any operation in the same table you create the `before trigger` for. So most likely the code you show is not the actual code you are seeing.

Comment: Yep, I just updated the logic that I was showing in my original question. You're right, It was wrong previously.

Comment: Well since you edited your code changing the table you do the select, the problem is like I said in previous comment. You can't do any select operation in the same table you created your `before trigger`

Comment: I give an answer a while ago to another person solving the same problem.  I'm trying to find it to post there so you can see.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38598664/460557

Comment: @JorgeCampos `ORA-04084` error (the question you answered) and `ORA-04091` are two absolutely different things.

Comment: @JorgeCampos hmm... thank you, but I am already doing this as a before insert and I want to check all rows in the table to make sure there is no duplicate fk_id that is currently active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a trigger, use a UNIQUE function-based index:

```
create unique index myindex on mytable (case when active_flag=1 then fk_id end);
```

When active_flag is not 1, no entry will be stored in the index; when active_flag is 1 an entry will be stored - but an exception will be raised if the same fk_id is already there.

Comment: This seems to be working great. I am not super familiar with constraints, so this was a big help. Thank you!